# Lay out blocks on multiple columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I think a screenshot and a little diagram will speak for themselves.
This is what I have:
[image]

And this is the result I want:

[image]

So basically I want to say a div can be this big and if it's bigger then cut it and put the rest in the next raw. 
Any idea on how to do this simply?

Thank you

Comment: What effort have you made on your part? I mean did you think of something...may be just an approach? something that the community can add to? :)

Comment: using flex box, or masonry http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 1):

Use the flexbox in the following way:

```
flex-flow: column wrap;
```

This will set the `flex-flow` into columns, not rows(as in your example), they will align on the `cross-axis`. Wrap will mean that the elements are allowed to wrap and take up space on a second column.

Comment: Browser support in case someone wants to drop IE 9 http://caniuse.com/#search=flex-flow

Answer (score 0):

According to the description and to the *'Spanish'* column on your schema, you want a *newspaper-like* layout, with content that overflows on the next column.

CSS3 Column Module is useful for that, and is [relatively well supported by browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn), providing you use it with prefixes.

In this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/oocep90h/1/)**, I have defined a lang block element. By setting a `column-width` to the langs, we allow the 'lang' to ***break on multiple columns***.

**CSS:**

```
.lang {
    -webkit-column-width: 100px;
    -moz-column-width: 100px;
    column-width: 100px;
}
```